# Number of samples in scikit-Learn cost function for Ridge/Lasso regression

Tags: scikit-learn, lasso, ridge-regression, elastic-net

I am using scikit-learn to train some regression models on data and noticed that the cost function for [Lasso Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html#sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) is defined like this:

[image: formula1] ,

whereas the cost function for e.g. [Ridge Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html) is shown as:

[image: formula2] .

I had a look in the code ([Lasso](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/32f9deaaf/sklearn/linear_model/_coordinate_descent.py#L1128) & [Ridge](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/32f9deaaf/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py#L910)) as well and the implementations of the cost functions look like described above. I am confused why the `1/n_samples` factor is only present in the Lasso regression case.

From my perspective it makes sense to have a scaling of the residuals inversely proportional to the number of samples [image: inline1] so that if an algorithm is used on a dataset with more training samples the value of `alpha` should be somehow invariant to that. In the [Elastic Net](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html#sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html) class, which can be understood as a combination of Lasso and Ridge regression, we also see that factor of `1/n_samples`. Can someone explain why this factor is not present in the cost function of Ridge regression?

Comment: The `sklearn` library has a github. Have you asked the maintainers why they made this choice? They would know the authoritative answer, if one exists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I posted the question on github as well now: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/discussions/23407

Comment: Yeah I came across the same issue recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72260808/mismatch-between-statsmodels-and-sklearn-ridge-regression I'm interested to see what the maintainers' rationale is

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/575814/232706

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the standartization $\gamma = \frac{c}{n}$, where $n$ is the sample size, aims to make regularization term $\alpha$ invariant to different sample sizes. This makes sense for Lasso-like models that compute coefficients coordinate-wise via soft-thresholding:
$$
\mathbf{w}_j \leftarrow \mathcal{S}_{\alpha}\Big(\frac{1}{n} \langle \mathbf{x}_j, \mathbf{r}_j \rangle \Big) = \text{sign} \Big(\frac{1}{n} \langle \mathbf{x}_j, \mathbf{r}_j \rangle \Big) \Big(|\alpha| - \frac{1}{n} \langle \mathbf{x}_j, \mathbf{r}_j \rangle \Big)_+
$$
Same with Elastic Net.

But in case of Ridge, which has a closed-form solution, I believe multiplication by $\gamma$ will be redundant and uninformative. First, let us quickly derive the solution:

$$
\min_{\mathbf{w}} \big\{ \| \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\mathbf{w} \|_2^2 + \alpha \| \mathbf{w} \|_2^2 \big\} \\
\frac{d}{d\mathbf{w}}\Big[ (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\mathbf{w})^T(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\mathbf{w}) + \alpha\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w} \Big] = \mathbf{0} \\
-2 \mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\mathbf{w}) + 2\alpha\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\mathbf{w}) - \alpha\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{w}^* = (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X} + \alpha\mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}
$$
Now, what happens if we multiply the loss by $\gamma$? We end up with something like this:
$$
\mathbf{w}_{\gamma}^* = (\gamma\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X} + \alpha\mathbf{I})^{-1}\gamma\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}
$$
or using matrix factorization like SVD:
$$
\mathbf{w}_{\gamma}^{SVD} = \mathbf{V}(\gamma\mathbf{D}^2 + \alpha\mathbf{I})^{-1} \gamma\mathbf{D}\mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{y} \\
\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{V}^T
$$
So, what does this standartization involve? Сan we explicitly state that it produces invariant results? (maybe the dual formulation will shed some light on this)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I do not see your point why a multiplication by $\gamma$ would be redundant. After all, in the end the optimal set of weights has a different form than in the case without the multiplication by $\gamma$. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @Holgerillo Weights indeed will be different. My conjecture is that multiplying by $\gamma$ is useless for a closed-form solution. If you calculate $\mathbf{w}^*$ or $\mathbf{w}^*_{\gamma}$ with resampling and optimization of $\alpha$, you will likely have values of optimal $\alpha$ of different scales in both cases, while for Lasso and Elastic Net you can expect the values to be almost identical with multiplication by $\gamma$.